# Go tutorial: Channels, Buffered Channels tutorial

Tags: go

I am going through Go's official tutorial and have difficulty understanding the difference between Channel and Buffered Channels. The links to the tutorials are https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2 and https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/3

In the Channel tutorial, Channel c first received the sum of [7, 2, 8] which is 17 and then received the sum of [-9, 4, 0] which is -5. When reading from c, it first output -5 to x and then 17 to y, in LIFO order:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func sum(s []int, c chan int) {
    sum := 0
    for _, v := range s {
        sum += v
    }
    c <- sum // send sum to c
}

func main() {
    s := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}

    c := make(chan int)
    go sum(s[:len(s)/2], c)
    go sum(s[len(s)/2:], c)
    x, y := <-c, <-c // receive from c

    fmt.Println(x, y, x+y)
}
```

(The above output is -5 17 12)

In the Buffered Channel tutorial, the output is 1 2, in FIFO order:

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 2)
    ch <- 1
    ch <- 2
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

Why are they different?

Comment: In your first example it is FIFO `{-9,4,0}` is the first slice and `{7,2,8}` is the second slice. output is also like First `-5` and second `17`

Comment: No. 1st slice (which is `s[:len(s)/2]`) is referring to `0 to len(s)/2 (-1)`.

Comment: All channels are FIFO, no matter if buffered or not. Your assumption about which value goes in first is wrong. Since goroutines run concurrently, you can't predict which sum gets to send its result first. Run these programs often enough and you should see the output change eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chnnael `c`, in your 1st example of unbuffered channel, is not acting as LIFO.

Actually it is happening because of `go routines`. The `go routines` executes concurrently.

If you tweak your code to debug, add one extra line in sum to print the sum before sending to channel.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func sum(s []int, c chan int) {
    sum := 0
    for _, v := range s {
        sum += v
    }
    fmt.Println("slice:", s)
    fmt.Println(sum)
    c <- sum         // send sum to c
}

func main() {
    s := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}

    c := make(chan int)
    go sum(s[:2], c)
    go sum(s[2:4], c)
    go sum(s[4:6], c)
    x, y, z := <-c, <-c, <-c // receive from c
    fmt.Println(x, y, z, x+y+z)
}
```

The output is:

```
slice: [4 0]
4
slice: [7 2]
9
slice: [8 -9]
-1
4 9 -1 12
```

So, you can see that `x` receives the 1st number that was sent through channel.

Furthermore, unbuffered channels sends data directly to receiver.

If you wanna know about the architecture of channels in `go`, you can watch [this talk of `gophercon-2017`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBZlN0izeiY). I found this talk very helpful.